# Records not saving in Sqlite database in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I want to save and retrieve data from my Sqlite database . For this I created a database name testDB.
I use this function to copy the database file to its phone storage by using this function

```
 public async void UpDatabase()
 {
    bool isDatabaseExisting = false;
    try
    {
        StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("testDB.db");
        isDatabaseExisting = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        isDatabaseExisting = false;
    }
    if (!isDatabaseExisting)
    {

        StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("testDB.db");
        await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
    }
}
```

But when I am inserting and retrieving record it works fine but when I close the project and emulator and reopened again all the data is lost and it get back to its original state.

Here is my code

```
class test
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is my inserting code

```
try
{
    var dbpath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "testDB.db");
    using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
    {
           db.Insert(new test()
           {
             Name = "abc",
            }
           );
           db.Commit();
           db.Dispose();
           db.Close();
    }
}
catch { }
```

Here is my retrieving code

```
 ry
{
    var dbpath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "testDB.db");
    using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
    {


       var q= from n in db.Table<test>()
              select n;


       foreach (var item in q)
       {
           list.Items.Add(item.Name);
       }
        db.Commit();
        db.Dispose();
        db.Close();
        var line = new MessageDialog("Registered successfully");
        line.ShowAsync();
    }
}
catch { }
```

Need help to maintain and store its data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the emulator always sets it back to its original state. That includes all settings and files. If you want your changes to be persistent you have to either test your code on an actual device or leave the emulator open while developing your app.

If you need your database set up for testing purposes everytime you start your app for the first time after restarting the emulator you can simply set a flag in the settings store like this and test against it:

```
if(!LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey("DBUploaded") {
    // Upload your database
    [..]
    // Once you're done, set the flag so that it's not uploaded again next time
    LocalSettings.Values.Add("DBUploaded", true)
}
```

Comment: @user3814490 The Windows Phone 8.1 emulator supports the concept of checkpoints, so you can populate the database and create a checkpoint for that. This is also helpful when changing language/region settings and such. Tap the double-arrows und use the "Checkpoint" tab.